# Show that a set $ \mathcal{O} \subseteq \mathbb R$ must be equal to $\mathbb R$.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I want to find a set $\mathcal{O}$ that satisfies the following definition
[image] :
$$\exists \varepsilon  > 0 : \forall x \in \mathcal{O} \; \text{it is} \; (x-\varepsilon,x + \varepsilon ) \subseteq \mathcal{O}$$

I think the only set that would work in this case would be the set of all real numbers, but I'm not sure how to go about proving it.

Comment: You could create a sequence of $x\in O$ that is not bounded and such that $x_{i-1}\in (x_i-\epsilon,x_i+\epsilon)$

Comment: ${\cal O} = \emptyset$ satisfies this condition vacuously.

Answer (score 2):

The set $\mathcal{O}$ is clearly open (it is the union of the intervals $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$ for $x\in \mathcal{O}$). On the other hand, it is also closed. To see this, let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{O}$ converging to a real number $x$. Then $|x_n-x|<\varepsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$. But then $x$ belongs to the interval $(x_n-\varepsilon,x_n+\varepsilon)$, which is contained in $\mathcal{O}$ by hypothesis. Thus $x\in \mathcal{O}$.

Conclusion: $\mathcal{O}$ is both open and closed. But the only such subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are $\varnothing$ and $\mathbb{R}$ itself.

I apologize if topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is out of the scope of the question.

---

In case you want to understand the above argument, let me provide the necessary definitions.

Here are two definitions for a subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}$:

- $X$ *open* if it is a union of open intervals.
- $X$ is *closed* if its complement in $\mathbb{R}$ is open.

It's a simple exercise to show that $X$ is closed if and only if it is closed under taking limits: if $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $X$ converging to a point $x\in \mathbb{R}$, then $x\in X$.

Finally, a set is *clopen* if it is both closed and open. Trivially, the sets $\varnothing$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are clopen.

The topology theorem I used above is the following.

> **Theorem:** The only clopen subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are $\varnothing$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

This theorem is actually notably difficult to prove, so a lot of details are swept under the rug here.

Answer (score 2):

If $x \notin \mathcal{O}$, then $(x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon)$ is disjoint from $\mathcal{O}$ (for the given $\varepsilon$ as in the condition on $\mathcal{O}$): if not, $p \in \mathcal{O}$ existed with $|x-p| < \varepsilon$, but this in turn implies that $x \in (p-\varepsilon,p+\varepsilon) \subseteq \mathcal{O}$ which is a contradiction. Hence $\mathcal{O}$ is closed and as $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, $\mathcal{O}=\emptyset$ or $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{R}$. Both do satisfy the condition...

Answer (score 0):

If $O \not = \emptyset$ then

Suppose $O \not= \mathbb{R} $, then there exist $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y \notin O$

Let $x \in O$, suppose $x>y$, then there exists $\delta = sup\{s>0:(-s + x,x+\varepsilon)\subset O\}$

Then $a = -\delta + x +\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \in O $

Then $(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon) \subset O$

Then $(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)\cup(x-\delta,x+\varepsilon) \subset O$

But $(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)\cup(x-\delta,x+\varepsilon) = (a-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon) = (-\delta -\frac{\varepsilon}{2} + x, x + \varepsilon)$

This contradicts that $\delta$ was the supreme

The same if $x<y$

Then $O = \mathbb{R}$

Comment: And what about $\mathcal{O} = \emptyset$?

Comment: You are right, 
I overlooked the trivial case...